# Import and display excel file in PHP from another directory. I want to read excel and display its conten

Tags: php, phpexcel, excel-import

I want to import an excel file in PHP from another directory. I want to read excel and display its content but its in another diretory and I'm getting an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in F:\Xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 3
```

## import.php

```
<form action="upload.php" >
<input name="file" type="file">
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

## upload.php

```
<?php 
$uploadedStatus = 0; 
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For showing excel in php you can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) like this:

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = 'MyExcelFile.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

to upload a file you can use [simple file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) like this:

PHP "upload.php":

```
<?php
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
              echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
               echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
              }
        }
    ?>
```

HTML form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

PHPExcel - DEAD
PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019.

The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or another alternative.

Comment: I update my post. PHPExcel - DEAD. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019.

Comment: Any alternatives for similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form have the `enctype` attribute for handling file uploads.

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

References:

1. [Importing excel files using PHP](http://www.discussdesk.com/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-PHP.htm)
2. [PHP Excel reader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)